# get user-specified values into javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a google maps application in which map settings are defined in a js file (map.js) as follows:

```
function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.133633, -11.469928);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
```

My home page (index.php) calls this script. 
I’d like to let users specify latitude, longitude, zoom level and map type. To this end I’ve created a form (setMap.htm), a client-side validation script (setMap.js), and setMap.php, which validates and sanitizes user input.

However, I’m not clear on how to get user-specified values into map.js.
Could I use ajax in map.js?:

```
function loadData(){

    $.getJSON('setMap.php', . . . . ?
```

And how do I replace the hardcoded values in function initialize() with the results of this call?

Do I need an ajax call in setMap.php as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in many ways.
One you just posted:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

```
$.getJSON( "setMap.php", function( data ) { // Do something here });
```

Your setMap.php just have to return valid json data.

You can also echo data straight into js value during request: echo 'var = {some data}' but I think it's not "nice" solution.

One more option is: don't use server side part. Just fetch data from form using JS, validate it and use without php reprocessing (if you don't need to save it somewhere you actually don't need to validate it on the server side)

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1
You should have

```
var map = google.maps.Map();
map.setOptions({your_options});
```

So you just fetch options from your form and fix map options in flight with no page reload or ajax request.

```
// html
<input id="zoom" type="text" />

// js code
var map;
function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.133633, -11.469928);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
}
function update() {
        var options = {};
        options.zoom = $('input#zoom').val();
        map.setOptions{options};
}
```

BUT PLEASE! This is just not tested pseudocode!

Comment: I'll look through that link thoroughly. 

I'm also interested in the third option you propose.

Comment: I appreciate your help but I don't know how to fetch options from the html form and put them in the javascript code. How do the values 42.133633, 13, ROADMAP get accessed and changed in initialize()?

Comment: Uh... so you get hard rock as the beginner in js/php.
If you have jQuery included in your page you can fetch values of a form fieldset as I mentioned `$('input#zoom').val();` where 'zoom' is input ID.
You create new LatLng with options you need in update function: `var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(X, Y);` and put it in the options in the same way zoom was put: `options.center = latlng`
It should be cake for someone who knows anything about js/html
http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=pl#LatLng

Comment: Thanks. I'd forgotten.